# Change Taskbar Icon Using PInvoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke, taskbar

I have an application that launches a windowed process. I have successfully managed to update the window icon as well as the icon displayed when using Alt+Tab using the following:

```
public class ProcessLauncher {

    ...

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int message, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private const int WM_SETICON = 0x80;
    private const int ICON_SMALL = 0;
    private const int ICON_BIG = 1;

    public void LaunchProcess() {

        var process = new Process();
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = "C:"
            };
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(50);

        var icon = Resources.MyIcon;

        SendMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, icon.Handle);
        SendMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, icon.Handle);
    }

    ...
}
```

This works just fine, but the taskbar icon for that process remains unchanged. How can I update the taskbar icon to match the icon I've supplied for the window and Alt+Tab?

Comment: What version of Windows is this on? Note you cannot change the taskbar icon for a program pinned to the taskbar (in Windows 7/8/10) that isn't running.

Comment: @Dai The process is one that my app launches, not one that is pinned or not running. I've updated the code in my question to reflect that.

Comment: The code looks very fake so answers can't be reliable.  But basic issue is that the code uses the MainWindowHandle property far too soon, before the process had a chance to create the window.  Add `process.WaitForInputIdle()`.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my sample again. None of the code I had posted was fake with the exception of supplying dummy values for my icon name and ProcessStartInfo.Arguments. To be as clear as possible, my code works as I expect. The process launches fine. The process' window opens fine. The icon of the window titlebar for that process updates fine. The icon displayed when you switch between application windows using Alt+Tab for displays fine. Only the taskbar icon does not. It displays as a Windows logo. Is there a way to update the taskbar icon of the process my app launches?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to change the icon from the inside?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what do you mean by change the icon from the inside? The window that I'd like to change the taskbar icon for is a process that my app launches, not a window that is part of my app that I would have direct design control over.

Comment: Suppose the app is my app. Why would I be happy that you might change the appearance of my app?

Comment: That's a fair question. But in my use case, it makes sense to me. I'm opening up a command prompt to run commands specific to my program and would like to give visual indication that the prompt is intended for my app's use. If user testing tells me that this is misleading, I'll change the functionality accordingly. Regardless of use case, is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I think that I would create a separate console app that did nothing more than create a cmd.exe process and wait for it to return. Then you could give your host app your icon and avoid all the hacking.

Comment: Thanks David. I hadn't thought of going that direction with it. Something along the lines of what you're suggesting will probably work for my needs.